# Link tag a with image background not working

Tags: html, css

I write a link tag and add an image with css background. The problem that the link tag doesn't work? Can someone fix me?

HTML

```
`<li class='n1'><a href='guiness.html'></a></li>`
```

CSS

```
.nav-mobile .n1{
background: url(/img/menu/expo.png) no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
background-position: right;
```

}

Comment: html
`<li class='n2'><a href='guiness.html'></a></li>`

Comment: add the html inside the question not as a comment

Comment: are you using class `.n1` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There need to be text inside for the `a` tag to work, so please add some dummy text, then use `text-indent:-9999px` to hide the text. This is based on the fact, that you are fixed on using `background` CSS property to be used!

Please refer the below JSFiddle and try to implement

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

Here is a simpler method using the `img` tag.

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>


Please use CSS to style the image tag based on your requirements!